# Is there a reliable way to send email without having the senders smtp?

Tags: email

My application will be used in a manner that the user is remote from his computer running the application, receiving data via text messages sent periodically from the PC.  Im sending the text message via email, using the number@carrierdomain.com.  To simplify determining the user's smtp server, I've been sending the message using the destination phone carrier's smtp, instead of the whatever may or may not be available at the PC.  This has worked so far with AT&T and T-Mobile, but not Verizon, as they have discontinued their smtp service.

I'm using mailsend v1.15 http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/mailsend/mailsend.html
but Im open to alternatives.

I do have a less than ideal workaround, which is to use google or hotmail's smtp, but that requires a login/pass.

If I can send the text through regular email, using outlook, it works.  I've looked at outlooks smtp logs, but that doesn't really help.

If its not being sent to a Verizon smtp server, how does it get routed, and is it something that my application can use?

Is there a reliable way to send email without having the senders smtp?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, any smtp server can send your e-mail. However, due to the overwhelming amount of spaming on the internet, pretty much every isp has locked down their smtp server and will not allow anonymous relaying of e-mail.

If you do have the outlook client on the box you are sending the e-mail you can look at using one of the Outlook APIs: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx
to send the e-mail message. You are using the outlook configuration then and don't have to worry about it your code.

Comment: The hope is to require as little as possible from the user, my software, an internet connection, and a phone to receive the text.

Comment: @ToddMuir: it's the correct solution though, given todays spam situation. You need to have a believable senders address. "MAPI" would be the generalized API which covers more than just Outlook.

Comment: Is this really simpler than using gmail's smtp server?  That doesnt require any apis at all, and requires less info from the user, a login and password, since the smtp is known.

Comment: No, it's not really simpler than using Gmail's SMTP server, but possibly more robust, in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

As long as an SMTP server is configured to allow relay from a remote domain then you can use it send email from/to virtually any address. There are downsides, however, to using *any* SMTP server to send an email from a specific domain - the most notable of which is that the recipient's domain will likely flag the message as spam because the domain of the SMTP server is different from that of the sender's email address.

There are other non-email APIs that can be used to send text messages, if that is something you're willing to consider. Check out:

- Tropo (http://www.tropo.com)
- Zeep Mobile (http://www.zeepmobile.com)

Best of luck to you.

Comment: this answer didn't age well... both links are dead! :D

Comment: Yeah, at this point I'd probably just point to Twilio.

Answer (score -2):

Impossible. SMTP is the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, without this is impossible to access to another account with Email format. You can make a php mail where you don't need to have smtp, but your access will be limited, not all ESP / ISP will allow you to delivery those emails, because they need to identify you using your SMTP and MX Lookup (Reverse MX A records) from your server. It exists more ways, but are 100% SPAMMERS and HACKERS methods and I don't recommend to use them.

Comment: Be careful with your answer, it isn't impossible as the question is phrased. There is some good advice in your response, but I think you may have misread the question.